# Insert from DataTableAdapter is not reflected in the MS Access Database!

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, ms-access, dataset

I am using MS Access as my Database and using Dataset for retrieval and update for my WPF app.
The data is shown in a datagrid without issues.
However, when i try to insert data using the following code, the insert is completed successfully, but the new row cannot be seen in the Access file.

```
var add = new AddressBookDataSet();
            adc.Fill(add.Address);
            var v = add.Address.NewAddressRow();
            v.StreetAddress = textBoxStreetAddress.Text;
            v.AtPost = textBoxAtPost.Text;
            v.Taluka = textBoxTaluka.Text;
            v.District = textBoxDistrict.Text;
            v.State = textBoxState.Text;
            v.Pincode = textBoxPincode.Text;
            v.PhoneNumber1 = textBoxContact1.Text;
            v.PhoneNumber2 = textBoxContact2.Text;
            v.PhoneNumber3 = textBoxContact3.Text;
            v.PhoneNumber4 = textBoxContact4.Text;
            v.FaxNumber1 = textBoxFax1.Text;
            v.FaxNumber2 = textBoxFax2.Text;
            add.Address.AddAddressRow(v);
            add.Address.AcceptChanges();
            //adc.Insert(textBoxStreetAddress.Text, textBoxAtPost.Text, textBoxTaluka.Text, textBoxDistrict.Text, textBoxState.Text, textBoxPincode.Text, textBoxContact1.Text, textBoxContact2.Text, textBoxContact3.Text, textBoxContact4.Text, textBoxFax1.Text, textBoxFax2.Text);
```

What could be the issue here? I checked the .accdb is not marked read-only!
here, 1 field **v.Id** has been ommitted as the Id field is an autonumber!
also, before going with creating a new Row, I tried the **adc.Insert** (i.e. TableAdapter.Insert) yet it doesn't update in the DB!!

Comment: Do you have an insert command?

Comment: Yes, I do.
The issue has been resolved, I was seeing the file in the source directory, while the file in the /bin/debug/ directory was being modified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this was not a real issue, yet the solution:

The **Access** file which gets modified while debugging is present in the **/Project/bin/debug** folder, and not the location used for storage of the file!!

So the changes are visible in the copy of the accdb file in the Debug folder.